# Uri из пути песни

Tags: android

Вообщем мне нужно получить uri файлов по их пути на телефоне и наоборот по uri получить ссылку на песню. Может кто знает?

Comment: `URI` можно создать прямо из файла (или из его пути, как строки). Чтобы получить файл по `URI`, придется спросить его у системы: https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20get%20file%20from%20uri&es_th=1

Answer (score 1):

Получаем uri файла так:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(<path_to_file>));
```

Созданный таким образом uri будет иметь scheme "file", и обратно конвертируется так:

```
String filePath = uri.getPath()
```